# Error 404 al llamar a función de Java externo desde un servlet

Tags: java, jsp

He escrito un servlet que recibe un usuario, una contraseña y una acción a realizar mediante `POST`. La acción determina el curso a seguir, en este caso, es un login, por lo que llama a su correspondiente función dentro del servlet, la cual devuelve al index un mensaje u otro dependiendo del resultado del login.

Esta función es la siguiente:

```
private static void loginUsuario(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException, ServletException{
        ManejoUsuarios mu = new ManejoUsuarios();

        if(mu.loginUser(req.getParameter("username"), req.getParameter("password")) == true){
            req.setAttribute("acierto", "El usuario existe");
            req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }else{
            req.setAttribute("mensaje", "Accion no proporcionada o desconocida");
            req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }
    }
```

Mi clase `ManejoUsuarios` está diseñada así:

```
public class ManejoUsuarios {
    public boolean loginUser(String username, String password){
        Usuario user = null;
        if(username.startsWith("U",0)){
            user = new Usuario(username, password, "alumno");
        }else if(username.startsWith("P", 0)){
            user = new Usuario(username, password, "profesor");
        }else{
            return false;
        }

        UsuarioJDBC ujdbc = new UsuarioJDBC();
        if(ujdbc.checkLogin(user)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Al hacer la llamada me devuelve un error 404. Veo que la función `loginUsuario` recibe bien los parámetros, y la clase `ManejoUsuarios` está importada dentro del servlet.

He probado obligando a la función `loginUser` de `ManejoUsuarios` a devolver un true tal que así:

```
public boolean loginUser(String username, String password){
    return true;     
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la URL del servlet?

Comment: La URL es la siguiente con la acción a realizar es la siguiente:

_localhost:8080/SGAPropio/controller/servletControlador?accion=login_


Estoy comprobando que **sí llama a la función**, por lo que el problema debe estar en el redireccionamiento. Aún así, no encuentro qué problema puede haber. 
Mi `index.jsp` está en la raíz de la carpeta "Web Pages", y el servlet está en un paquete "controller".

Comment: Parece que acabo de resolverlo.
En mi `index.jsp` tenía la siguiente llamada en el formulario:

`<form name="login_form" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controller/servletControlador?accion=login"  method="post" onsubmit="return validarForm(this);">`

Investigando, he visto que las rutas a cañón y los `POST` no se llevan bastante bien, así que cambié la llamada por la siguiente:

`<form name="login:form" action="?accion=login" method="post" onsubmit="return validarForm(this);">`

Ahora si me redirige a mi `index.jsp`

Answer (score 0):

[Javadoc de getRequestDispatcher()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)):

> Returns a RequestDispatcher object that acts as a wrapper for the resource located at the given path. A RequestDispatcher object can be used to forward a request to the resource or to include the resource in a response. The resource can be dynamic or static.
>
> The pathname specified may be relative, although it cannot extend outside the current servlet context. If the path begins with a "/" it is interpreted as relative to the current context root. This method returns null if the servlet container cannot return a RequestDispatcher.

Así que si quieres hacer forward al recurso "/index.jsp" tienes que hacer

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```